# Volume of shell by integration

Tags: definite-integrals, volume, solid-of-revolution

I came across this question in my textbook:

What's the volume generated by rotation of the intersected area between the two curves $Y=X^5$ and $Y=X$ around the axis $X=-1$?

My main problem is the value of r with which I should substitute in the shell formula $dv=2πrhdt$. I believe it should be ($r=x+1$) while my text book substitutes ($r=x$).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

$r$ is the distance from the axis of rotation, and so it is $x+1$ (and $h = x-x^5$). You could use $r=x$ if you compensated for this horizontal shift elsewhere, but I don't know if that's what your book did.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer! You considered the shape as a washer. My question is about the shell method though. Also the axis of rotation is parallel to the Y-axis, not the X-axis.

Comment: In that case, you would have $r = y^{1/5}-y$ (note that you would have to parameterize in terms of $y$).

Comment: Why did you define r in terms of y, not x? The integration variable should be x, afterall!

Comment: The shell method is only used when the axis of rotation is perpendicular to  the independent variable axis. For this problem, if you want $x$ to be the independent variable, then you have to use the washer method.

Comment: The axis of rotation is x=-1; parallel to y-axis.

Comment: My bad, I fixed the post.

Comment: I did this problem by a independent method known as Pappus's $(2^{nd})$ Centroid Theorem (with is somewhat simpler). I'd like to know what you got for the volume to see if this agrees. I did the problem over the space $x,y\in[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this volume calculation using Pappus's $(2^{nd})$ Centroid Theorem: the volume of a planar area of revolution is the product of the area $A$ and the length of the path traced by its centroid R, i.e., $2πR$. The volume is simply $V=2\pi RA$.

The figure below shows the area to be revolved about the line $x=-1$. Notice that I've expressed the area in the region $x\in[-1,1]$. It apparent that the centroid $R=1$ and the area is

$$A=2\int_0^1 (x-x^5)\,dx=\frac{2}{3}$$

Hence,

$$V=\frac{4\pi}{3}$$

How does this compare with that of anyone else?

[image: The area being rotaed]